# What is the status code of asynchronous request

Tags: http, erlang

Is there any way to get the status code when doing an asynchronous request using `httpc:request`? Ideally, I would also like to get the body of the response.

Documentation states:

> **stream**
>
> Streams the body of a 200 or 206 response to the calling process or to a file. When > streaming to the calling process using option self, the following stream messages are sent to that process: `{http, {RequestId, stream_start, Headers}}`, `{http, {RequestId, stream, BinBodyPart}}`, and `{http, {RequestId, stream_end, Headers}}`.
>
> When streaming to the calling processes using option `{self, once}`, the first message has an extra element, that is, {http, `{RequestId, stream_start, Headers, Pid}}`. This is the process id to be used as an argument to `httpc:stream_next/1` to trigger the next message to be sent to the calling process.
>
> Notice that chunked encoding can add headers so that there are more headers in the stream_end message than in stream_start. When streaming to a file and the request is asynchronous, the message `{http, {RequestId, saved_to_file}}` is sent.
>
> Default is none.

Which is really unhelpful...

Imagine this situation:

```erlang
receive_payload(Pid, RequestId, Url) ->
    httpc:stream_next(self()),
    Timeout = 500,
    receive
        {http, {RequestId, stream_start, Headers}} ->
            io:fwrite("Started ~s~n", [Url]);
        {http, {RequestId, stream, BinBodyPart}} ->
            io:fwrite("Receiving ~s~n", [Url]);
        {http, {RequestId, stream_end, Headers}} ->
            io:fwrite("Finished ~s~n", [Url]),
            Pid ! {done, Url}
    after Timeout ->
            io:fwrite(
              "Nothing was received after ~.b ms from ~s~n",
              [Timeout, Url]
             ),
            Pid ! {err, {missing_req, Url}, timeout}
    end.

process_rec(Pid, {Url, Checksum, Meta, Script, Src}) ->
    HttpOpts = [{timeout, 1000}, {ssl, [{verify, 0}]}],
    %% Opts = [{sync, false}, {stream, self}, {receiver, self()}],
    Opts = [{sync, false}, {receiver, self()}],
    Resp = httpc:request(get, {Url, []}, HttpOpts, Opts),
    io:fwrite("Response ~w~n", [Resp]),
    case Resp of
        {ok, RequestId} -> receive_payload(Pid, RequestId, Url);
        {error, Error} -> Pid ! {err, {missing_req, Url}, Error}
    end.
```

If you get any HTTP status beside 200 or 206, you will simply get a timeout, even though the information about the error should be available as well as a status code, if the server replied with something like 400 "not found" etc.

---

PS. I'm not interested in solutions that involve third-party libraries.